# How do I scan all elements within a class to find a specific id and repeat the process for different ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new to jquery, so please excuse me if I'm doing something stupid:

I have a table where each td belongs to the same class "original" and each one has a unique id.

```
<table id="main">
        <tr>
            <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original" id="1">
                one
            </td>
            <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original" id="2">
                two
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
        ...
</table>
```

I also have a div where all elements are part of a separate class "onclick" and each element has another unique id that is connected to each td from the table.

```
<div id="second">
        <div class="onclick" id="1click">
            Extra info about 1
            <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="onclick" id="2click">
            Extra info about 2
            <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
        </div>
        ...
        ...
</div>
```

When I click on each individual td, I want to display its corresponding div, so if I click on "1" then "1click" shows up. I currently have this jquery code that successfully does this, but only for the first pair of elements, so it doesn't work for anything beyond id="1" and id="1click".

```
$(function () {
    $(".original").click(function() {
        var divname = this.id;
        if ($(".onclick").attr("id") == divname + 'click'){
            var clickname= "#" + divname + "click";
            if ($(".hide").css("display") == 'none'){
                $(clickname).toggle();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make it so that it searches each element of the table to find a match with each element of the div?

Thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding it difficult understanding what you're trying to do and would love to help but I need to try and understand it better.

1) You can search using `.each()` which will scan all the elements and you can use a conditional statement to find the one which is needed: I.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "2") {
        var element = $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"click");
        // do stuff with element
    }
  })
});
```

I created a small example which I think helps your scenario on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/keuhfu36/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#i2click").click(function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
  $("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "i2") {
      $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"click").click();
    }
  });
});
```

2) I recommend you change the div values from `id='1'` and `id='2'` like i did in the example to a value which starts with a letter i.e `id="i1"` and `id="i2"` which makes it **a lot** less of a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should be like ,

```
$(".original").click(function() {
  var divId = this.id,
      targetDiv = $("#"+divId+"click");
  $(".onclick:visible").hide();
  targetDiv.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
$(function(){
$('.onclick').hide();  

$(".original").click(function() {    
    var divname = this.id;
 
    $('#'+divname+'click').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {

    $(".original").click(function() {

        // Targeted Div Name
        var divname = "#"+ $(this).attr('id') + "click";

        // Toggle the div, as Id would be unique in the page
        $(divname).toggle();

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original" id="1">
      one
    </td>
    <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original" id="2">
      two
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="second">
  <div class="onclick" id="1click">
    Extra info about 1
    <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="onclick" id="2click">
    Extra info about 2
    <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, you should ditch the IDs altogether and just use the classes along with their indexes to achieve the desired effect much simpler, like this:

```js
$('#main').on('click', '.original', function() {
    var index = $('.original').index($(this)); // find the index of the clicked td
    $('.onclick').hide().eq(index).show(); // hide all the divs then show the one at the same index as the clicked td
  })
  .on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.onclick').hide(); // hide all the divs when "close" is clicked
  });
```

```css
.onclick {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original">
      one
    </td>
    <td style="cursor: pointer" class="original">
      two
    </td>
  </tr>
  ... ...
</table>

<div id="second">
  <div class="onclick">
    Extra info about 1
    <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="onclick">
    Extra info about 2
    <span class="close" style="cursor: pointer">&times;</span>
  </div>
  ... ...
</div>
```

Comment: You should explain the down vote. This is a much simpler solution than others suggested here. ;)